# What data structure container can be sorted by date

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

is there any data structure that can be sorted by date in Python 3?

```
('2015-08-01', 10,10)
('2015-08-03', 11,11)
.. and so on ..
```

I know i can use pandas dataframe, but like to know if there are other more lightweight alternatives.

Comment: Your 'dates' are just ISO-8601 formatted strings, which naturally sort lexicographically. So using a sequence of tuples, with the date as the first value, can be sorted directly. So would a sequence of lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the date is a string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, it's already sortable in the way you'd expect. And since the dates are the first item, you don't even need to provide a key function.

```
data = [('2015-08-03', 11,11), ('2015-08-01', 10,10)]

data.sort()

print(data)
```

Result:

```
[('2015-08-01', 10, 10), ('2015-08-03', 11, 11)]
```

---

If the date wasn't the first item, you could do this:

```
import operator

data = [('a', '2015-08-03', 11,11), ('b', '2015-08-01', 10,10)]

data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))

print(data)
```

Result:

```
[('b', '2015-08-01', 10, 10), ('a', '2015-08-03', 11, 11)]
```

Comment: can't believe its that simple, exactly what i needed, thanks